# Not all updates syncing between WSUS and SCCM 2012

Tags: wsus, update, sccm-2012-r2

I have a single server with both WSUS and SCCM 2012 R2 installed.  I'm pretty sure everything is configured correctly.  The only errors I'm seeing in the wsyncmgr.log file when I do a full synchronization relates to problems downloading EULA's for IE11 which is another issue I'll deal with later.

Right now the problem I'm wrestling with is that not all updates seem to be synchronizing between WSUS and SCCM.  For example, when I go into WSUS and search for a particular MS bulletin number (which I wont mention for security reasons).  I can find the Update in the WSUS console but, even after a full sync in SCCM I cannot find it under All Software Updates.

Does anyone have any suggestions of where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to figure it out for the most part.  When I searched the wsyncmgr.log file on the server for the particular KB number in question I found a message saying "Skipped update ... because it was superseded."

The only thing I want to try to figure out now is: OK it was superseded, but by what?

Comment: Had to do some google-fu but found this little gem: http://supersededmicrosoftpatches.com/

Answer (score 0):

It is superseded because you need to increase months when updates will be superseded. You can go to Administration, then Software Updates Point and then Supersedence Rules, increase the number on Do not expire a superseded updates...